# How to unlock an object larger than the page in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have an object larger than the pasteboard. Its lock icon is outside in the grey field and not visible.

How do I unlock that object?

Answer (score 5):

Object > Unlock All On Spread
or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for Mac
or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Windows (not tested, but should work)

That unlocks every item on the page; including your object.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you are in preview mode in InDesign. Although that's a nice mode to see what your work is going to look like when actually printed, it's sub-optimal for actual work.

Try hitting <kbd>W</kbd> to switch back the regular viewing mode. This will allow you to see the pasteboard and the bleed area, and it will most probably also pop up some useful guides and grids (if you've set them).

Since you can now see the pasteboard, you will be able to find and click your object's lock icon.